# No se me activa el boolean al usar Pattern y Matcher

Tags: java, eclipse, windows10

Segun mi codigo en java, deberia de buscarme en el nombre del fichero alguno de esos caracteres de mi Pattern, y activarme el boolean resultado si contiene alguno de esos caracteres.

Pero en el ejemplo que mando, siempre el boolean me devuelve falso. Debe de ser un fallo muy facil, pero no doy con el. Gracias.

```
public boolean prueba_avisarCambiarAcentosPorLetras() {

    File fichero = new File("palabrás que uso de prúeba.jhg");

    System.out.println("* Tengo este fichero : " + fichero);
    System.out.println("* Y digo voy a mirar si tiene ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ ");

    String caracteres = "[ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ]";

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(caracteres);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(fichero.toString());

    boolean resultado = false;
    resultado = mat.matches();

    System.out.println("* Tiene simbolos de esos? : " + resultado);

    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Del Javadoc, Matcher.matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern. 
>   If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.

Es decir, devolverá *true* si y solo todo el nombre del fichero está compuesto de esos símbolos.

Para ver que una parte del nombre contenga uno de esos símbolos, usa *Matcher.find()*.

Comment: Funciono correctamente ahora, el fallo es que como indicabas, que debia de usar Matcher.find(). Gracias.